# Firebase addValueEvent listener consuming memory if data is in large amount

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Thanks in advance.

```
global.getDatabaseReference().child(ApplicationConstants.TOPIC_DB).child(Util.getSelectedBoard(context)).child(Util.getSelectedClass(context)).child(Util.getSelectedLanguagePackage(context)).child("CategoryId_1").child(subject).child(ApplicationConstants.TOPICS).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {

                    topicContentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> modelHashMap = null;
                    int pos =0;
                    for (DataSnapshot single_ : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        modelHashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        HashMap<String, String> innerTopicNode = (HashMap<String, String>) single_.getValue();

                        innerTopicNode.put("mastery", "0");
                        innerTopicNode.put("enabled", innerTopicNode.get("Display"));
                        innerTopicNode.put("currentLevel", "1");
                        innerTopicNode.put("flag", "Done");
                        innerTopicNode.put("score", "0");

                        modelHashMap.put(pos + "", innerTopicNode);
                        pos++;
                        topicContentArrayList.add(modelHashMap);

                    }
                                     } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Util.dismissdataDialog();
            }
        });
```

Here is the memory error
Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 277003(9MB)
It is blocking the UI and I'm unable to perform click action for some time.
Please Help me to get out from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal behaviour when you trying to get large amount of data. If you want to avoid errors like this, you should consider loading your data in small chunks. To achieve this, you can [filter your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) using one of the methods that are provided by Firebase.

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, is there everything alright?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer but its not meet my requirement.
This is working fine now but stuck with another issue is What if I have to call the above code in loop having size 50.

In that case it is blocking the UI.

Comment: If you are stuck with another issue (other than this), please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Regarding this issue, have you tried loading your data in small chunks? Please also note, that Firebase Database client, already runs all network operations in a background thread. This means that all operations take place without blocking your main thread. Do you think that my answer helped you for the initial issue?

Comment: No. It did not help me to get out from that.